# Trouble setting the HTML of a variable in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I've done is loaded some HTML from a file and I am attempting to modify some elements within that HTML.

The initialization looks like this:

```
var id = player_info["ID"];
$("#main_container").append(
    $("<div />").attr({class: "player_container", id: "player_" + id}).css("display", "none")
);

// Add all information to the player container
var player_container = $("#player_" + id);
player_container.load("player_layout.html");
```

With `player_layout.html` looking like this:

```
<div class="player_name">

</div>
<div class="player_chips">
    Chips:
    <br/>
    <span class='bidding'></span>/<span class='chips'></span>
</div>
<div class="player_stats">
    Wins / Losses
    <br/>
    <span class="wins"></span>/<span class="losses"></span>(<span class="total_games"></span>)
    <br/><br/>
    Chips Won / Chips Lost
    <br/>
    <span class="chips_won"></span>/<span class="chips_lost"></span>
</div>
<button class="player_won">Player Has Won</button>
```

I then want to modify some of the elements, specifically classes. An example of the way I was initially doing this is:

```
player_container.find(".player_name").text(player_info['username']);
```

This wasn't working so I then tried to switch `find` with `children` and `text` with `html` but that didn't seem to work. I then tried this:

```
$('> .player_name', player_container).html(player_info['username']);
```

but that also didn't work. I understand that I can use DOM to grab the `childNodes` and compare the class names but there are a lot of classes that need modifying and I'd also like to know if this is possible in JQuery. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have no child of `player_container`

Comment: Missed a line of code while copying and pasting. Sorry.

Comment: When are you using `player_container.find(".player_name")`?

Comment: Can you post the content of `player_layout.html`

Comment: try with this $("#player_" + id) if you will get that

Comment: @Satpal I am using `player_container.find(".player_name")` after the load

Comment: @VforVendetta What do you mean?

Comment: You are saving id in player_container variable, instead try $("#player_" + id).find(".player_name") like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use complete callback method of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
var player_container = $("#player_" + id);
player_container.load("player_layout.html",  function(){
    player_container.find(".player_name").text(player_info['username']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot the callback.

Comment: Sorry, was waiting for countdown.